# Conditional pmf and mean for geometric rv

Tags: conditional-expectation, geometric-distribution

I have a geometric r.v. p(1-p)^(n-1), n = 1, 2, 3, 4, ...

I was able to figure out the conditional mean conditioned on X > a. My answer to this is E[X] + a. I am pretty sure that is correct but if not can anyone let me know where I went wrong.

I am not able to find the conditional pmf for the same condition. Any pointers that can help?
Thanks

Comment: Please add the `self-study` tag, read the guidelines in its [tag wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) and show what you tried so we can see what you need. You presumably know some simple facts about conditional probability already.

Comment: Perhaps you could post an outline of your answer so your question doesn't go unanswered.

Comment: The pmf is the geometric pmf divided by (1-p)^a

Comment: That's an answer (though it's strictly incorrect as it stands), but to count as an answer it wuold have to go in the answer box, not in the comment box, and as an answer to a self study question it should lean toward giving guidance rather than a full solution. I was trying to suggest you do something like write the first step or so and explain the approach required to finish it.